# Magento error when going to forgotten password link

Tags: magento2

Hi when we go to the 'Forgot Password' link of our Magento 2 store we see this error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setEmailValue()
>   on boolean in
>   /home/signedge/public_html/idcardsolutions.net/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/ForgotPassword.php:49
>   Stack trace: #0
>
> /home/signedge/public_html/idcardsolutions.net/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/ForgotPassword/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword->execute() #1
>
> /home/signedge/public_html/idcardsolutions.net/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword\Interceptor->execute()
>     #2
>
> home/signedge/public_html/idcardsolutions.net/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>     #3
>
> home/signedge/public_html/idcardsolutions.net/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array) #4
>
> /home/signedge/public_html/idcardsol in
>   /home/signedge/public_html/idcardsolutions.net/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/ForgotPassword.php
>   on line 49

ForgotPassword.php has not been modified in anyway.

What's strange is this only happens on one of our stores. Other stores from the same installation work fine.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: is your magento2 a migration from magento1?

Comment: Hi no it was not

Comment: do you use clean luma theme or do you made some changes?

Comment: it is a custom theme which was based on luma theme

Comment: so the custom theme is the issue, contact the theme developer's

Comment: I have applied the same theme to another substore and that is working fine with no error

Comment: I fixed this with setup:upgrade then static deploy - very weird!